# Req.body is always empty in node.js, even with a body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am just simply trying to post to my MongoDb database (I am new with Node.js), and I am able to post to my db with static data, but for some reason I cannot with trying to get the body of my request. It is always empty.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../db');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('landing');
});

router.post("/addfan", (req, res) => {
    var newFan = new db.Fans(req.body);
    console.log(newFan);
    newFan.save()
        .then(item => {
            res.send('saved');
        })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

My html page (actually an EJS file, but shouldn't matter) has a single text box that is connected to the '/addfan' action from the post-form. Sorry for the newbie question, but I am using a body-parser and have looked every else and cannot get my req.body to become non-empty.

Comment: In `/addfan` route handler, what's the output of `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: @ArchNoob /addfan is an action from my post in my form in my html. I logged req.body and it returns '{ fullname: 'adasd', Add: 'Submit' }' , which full name is the name of my textbox and the add submit corresponds to my submit button. But nothing get saved to my db.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. I was not aware that the name of my HTML fields had to correspond exactly to the schema for the JSON in my MongoDB.

Comment: Detailed logging is important to be sure what data are you passing along on your application.

Answer (score 0):

body-parser is application-level middleware. Change the 'router' to 'app':

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

[Link to GitHub repository of body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: or check your submiting data type.It's post not get.I am new with Node.js too.hope this helps